# Is there a "TUI" mode for standalone lldb?

Tags: lldb

Since gdb is getting onerous to work with on a Mac these days (at least I feel like I am fighting uphill against Apple), I've started to play around with lldb.

Is there an equivalent mode to `gdb -tui` that shows a nice, persistent view of the source and where you are in it when running lldb standalone from the command line? Obviously, in Xcode, there is such a display, but I deploy most of my code to Linux boxes eventually and would prefer to use the same development environment on both platforms (i.e., vim, Makefiles, autotools, etc.).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In top of tree svn source lldb there's a *very* new command line GUI mode that's been added by Greg Clayton.  It's pretty neat with separate windows for the source, local variables, stack, threads, registers, etc.  No console window yet.  It's pretty cool.  See http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html for how to build lldb from source if you'd like to check it out.  To enter the GUI mode, just type `gui` from the lldb command line when you're debugging.

UPDATE: this gui feature is included in the lldb that ships in Xcode 6 and later.  It's a nights-and-weekends side project that isn't seeing a lot of active development right now but give it a try.

Comment: Can you specify what version of LLDB would have this gui feature?

Comment: Greg's TUI-like mode is included in Xcode 6, released fall of 2014.  It's spare time fun project of Greg's -- it isn't as polished as other parts of the command line debugger -- but it works pretty well.

Comment: The gui mode is a god send. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Sadly, no.

However, I did came across this:
https://github.com/snarez/voltron

If you are familiar with screen/tmux it works pretty good.

Comment: Wow, this looks really cool too, sorry I missed this post when you made it.

Comment: By far the best lldb GUI out there atm

Answer (score 15):

Type `gui` in lldb's prompt after you're at an interesting breakpoint. It has a small tutorial the first time it's opened and built-in help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having good luck with a [free GUI facade from Affinic](http://www.affinic.com/?page_id=109). It's not perfect (or, at least, my understanding of it is not perfect). I must occasionally restart it and sometimes it gets unsynchronized from particularly gnarly / fancy C++ code, e.g., code that does a lot of implicit stuff in constructors. But overall it has saved me a lot of time over the old-fashioned way at the command line.

I have not been able to get the ncurses GUI mode in the LLDB CLI to work, and I have not tried Voltron.

Comment: Necropost: Affinic Debugger for GDB/LLDB has a "lite" and "pro" version. The "lite" version is what's free but it has (IMO) severe limits.