# Documentation for LLDB's GUI

Tags: user-interface, documentation, lldb

I've been recently been playing around with LLDB's gui feature. (A stackoverflow link about this feature is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820247/is-there-a-tui-mode-for-standalone-lldb/21658169#21658169). My current lldb is `lldb-320.4.156`)

So far, it seems very convenient, especially the ability to view local variables in the current stack frame. But is there any documentation (or tutorial) on how to use the LLDB's GUI mode?

---

**Aside**: I specifically have a few questions:

1. How to show the source code upon going into GUI mode. (Unless I stop at a breakpoint and type `gui` within LLDB, I can never get source code to show up.)
2. How to rerun a program while in GUI mode. (There is nowhere to type while in GUI mode.)
3. Are there colors in GUI mode? I notice if you type `lldb --help` in the command line, `lldb` tells you you could invoke it with a `--no-use-colors` option. (That being said, I've never seen colors with normal `lldb` mode...)
4. Is there a way to set breakpoints, prior to running `lldb`?

Comment: Just type `gui` command to activate TUI, and `ESC` back to command mode.

Answer (score 8):

The GUI mode in lldb is a feature that Greg Clayton did over a few weeks of nights & weekends -- it's a really cool hack.  But it's not completed to product-quality level and there's no documentation short of the command key tips that you can see with its built in help system.  The biggest omission is definitely the lack of a console window where you could type arbitrary lldb commands - but adding a console pane like that was where things started to get tricky. :)

Hopefully an interested developer will pick up the gui mode work and add these features.  For people who can't use a full IDE, it can be really helpful to have a text mode windowed UI when using a debugger.

Answer (score 5):

> *But is there any documentation (or tutorial) on how to use the LLDB's GUI mode?*

I don't know any official documentation. But [this random video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Yw1chhv7UQ&t=135) was helpful for me. Also, pressing <kbd>h</kbd> in TUI gives you a minimal documentation.

> *1. How to show the source code upon going into GUI mode. (Unless I stop at a breakpoint and type gui within LLDB, I can never get source code to show up.)*

As you observed, unless `gui` command is executed while the program is paused due to a breakpoint or something, nothing happens in TUI.

> *2. How to rerun a program while in GUI mode. (There is nowhere to type while in GUI mode.)*

AFAIK, impossible. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and execute `run` again.

> *3. Are there colors in GUI mode? I notice if you type lldb --help in the command line, lldb tells you you could invoke it with a --no-use-colors option. (That being said, I've never seen colors with normal lldb mode...)*

In my environment (M1 Macbook Air), color works with no option (i.e. by default) both in CUI and TUI.

> *4. Is there a way to set breakpoints, prior to running lldb?*

See [@Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500688/8776746). You can also use `~/.lldbinit` file if the breakpoint condition is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer for all your questions, but regarding breakpoints, you can save all your debug session "setup" commands in a file and then just load that file:

```
lldb -S <filename>
```

Found this option from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275770/1345329