# lldb - How to use the TUI

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb, tui

I have just found that lldb has a `gui` command that brings up a nice UI for command line debugging. However, I have no idea how to use it and could not find any reasonable documentation.

```bash
(llvm) gui
```

Brings up this kind of interface:
[image: lldb interface]

However, I cannot figure out how to interact with it, eg. send a command to step to the next line. Any idea? I am using Mac OSX Catalina, iterm2 and tmux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "TUI" mode for standalone lldb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820247/is-there-a-tui-mode-for-standalone-lldb)

Comment: @ThomasSablik My question is about how to interact with the gui, not how to open it. As you can confirm from the attached image, I have the TUI feature in my lldb but I am not sure if I need to setup something in order to tell it for example to "step".

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Have you found any solution? I have the same question.

Comment: @ynn Sorry, I found no solution either, had to use some remote debugging tools.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Thanks. I finally found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405776/8776746).